# Removal of multiple sub-folders in Ubuntu server doesn't work using curly brackets

Tags: command-line, server, xubuntu, directory, delete

I have a ubuntu(don't know the version) server, in which I am trying to clear the following 4 sub-folders.

```
magento-root/var/cache
magento-root/var/session
magento-root/var/log
magento-root/var/report
```

I know using the following 1-liner command I can clear all those folders, after I have `cd`ed to the `magento-root/` folder, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
rm -rf var/{cache,session,report,log}/*
```

What could be reason for this, is there any setting through which this can be turned off ?

Comment: Did you use the command with `sudo`?

Comment: Command works for me where I have appropriate permissions.

Comment: I don't have server sudo credentials, due to security risk, but I don't think `sudo` is required for using curly brackets for multiple folders whereas `rm -rf var/cache/*` works fine without need of `sudo` overrides. I can delete all those sub-folders separately, but if I run the 1-liner, it never works.

Comment: I didn't use `-rf` when I tested. Does it fail silently?

Comment: And you're just trying to delete what's inside the subdirectory right? Not the subdirectory itself.

Comment: Yes, only the content and not the folder itself.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the output of the curly brackets command? ...if there is output?

Comment: No output nor any errors. It fails without any messages, maybe due to some folders in the braces are already empty, the whole command is ignored further ?

Comment: What is the output of replacing the `rm -rf` command with `ls`.  This will help us to see what the command is seeing.

Comment: Is there any other 1-liner by which I can clear those folders regardless of they are empty or not ?

Comment: You could also enable verbose output by adding the `-v` option to `rm`. That might give some clues.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment `Is there any other 1-liner by which I can clear those folders regardless of they are empty or not ?` use this:

**other 1-liner**

Use this:

First make sure you are in the `magento-root/` directory.  Then run this line:

```bash
$ for i in var/cache var/session var/log var/report; do rm -rf $i/* ;done
```

If you are not in the `magento-root` directory use use this one liner `cd` to the `magento-root` directory:

```bash
 cd magento-root; for i in var/cache var/session var/log var/report; do rm -rf $i/* ;done
```